# Rail3 'Return False Unless XYZ' Query Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine

In my rails3.1 application, I'm trying to apply the following logic in one of my order model.

```
 def digital?
   line_items.map { |line_item| return false unless line_item.variant_id = '102586070' }
 end
```

I've created a separate variant called prepaid_voucher which has id = 102586070. Despite this,  the result is false...

> Order has many line_items
>
> LineItem belongs to order and variant
>
> Variant has many line_items

Is this the best way to perform such a task and how can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you want a double `==` here `line_item.variant_id = '102586070'`, then I rather go for something like that (If I understand what you want)

```
def digital?
  line_items.select{|line_item| line_item.variant_id == '102586070'}.any?
end
```

But it's hard to understand what you really want, what is the expected behavior if the id is not found?

Comment: Was trying to avoid an overly complex question. I'm using spree and am trying to alter the state of the cart process. I.e. if digital product go to x otherwise go to y. The above is still not working though :(

Comment: yeah I amended it several times, but that should respond true or false depending on the presence of the id (which btw should go in a constant or some more descriptive variable). Acccording with your code `return false unless` this is `return true if` => `.any?` should do, but maybe you want `.empty?` or `.blank?`

Comment: also make sure you haven't saved any object after that function or some of them could contain the variant id you assigned at the beginning with `=`

Comment: I've got to have something wrong with my variant_id because that's also not working. Looks right to me, will check through logs. Cheers